# the python problems about strings

Tags: python-3.x

```
def shut_down(s):
    s = s.Lower()
    if s  == 'yes' :
        return "Shutting down..."
    elif s ==  'no':
        return "Shutdown aborted!"
    else :
        return "Sorry, I didn't understand you."
```

the computer tell me that Your shut_down function threw the following error: 'str' object has no attribute 'Lower'

Comment: Python is a case-sensitive language. That method is named `lower()`, not `Lower()`.

Comment: Use `lower()` instead of `Lower()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.Lower()` is not available in python because it's case sensitive language use `.lower()`

```
     def shut_down(s):
         s = s.lower()

         if s  == 'yes' :
              return "Shutting down..."
         elif s ==  'no':
              return "Shutdown aborted!"
         else :
             return "Sorry, I didn't understand you."
```